# Error when running jest test on WSL2 running Ubuntu with the VS code IDE

Tags: javascript, node.js, unit-testing, jestjs, wsl-2

I'm using ubuntu on WSL2 and then open VS code IDE from Ubuntu and installed jest in my project root to test my web app. I added jest to package.json file and then run npm test on Ubuntu terminal running internally in VS code. I got an error as follows: '\wsl.localhost\Ubuntu\home\niyi74\projects\meadowlark\site' CMD.EXE was started with the above path as the current directory. UNC paths are not supported. Defaulting to Windows directory. Error: Could not find a config file based on provided values: path: "C:\Windows" cwd: "C:\Windows"

I have created jest.config.js file and change the file path to use forward slash, it didn't work.

Comment: you're trying to run `cmd.exe` in linux?